# Access static class variable from an Interface using a generic method?

Tags: java

Here is the class implementing the interface:

```
public class Dragon extends Character implements Actions {
    static int runRequirement = 95;
}
```

And the interface:

```
public interface Actions {
default <T> boolean run(T enemy) {
    if (Math.random() * 100 < T.runRequirement) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now... I know that T is a generic **type**, so it could be reasonable that a **type** cannot access a static variable, even if **it is** the name of the class, too.

However, I cannot access the static variable even doing something this:

```
T.getClass().runRequirement
```

or:

```
T.getClass().getName().runRequirement // getName() returns a String, but I tried it anyway...
```

or:

```
enemy.getClass().runRequirement
```

Simply: what am I doing wrong? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just do `enemy.runRequirement`

You can access static variables from instances

Comment: Doesn't work. Itellij IDEA marks it red and tells me "Cannot resolve symbol" :\

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection on the `class` of `enemy` object:

```
    public interface Actions {
        default <T> boolean run(T enemy) {
            int runRequirement = 0;
            try {
                Field field = enemy.getClass().getDeclaredField("runRequirement");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                runRequirement = Integer.parseInt(field.get(null).toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            if (Math.random() * 100 < runRequirement) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Seems a bit "too much" O_O And... NoSuchFieldException.

Comment: I tried the code like yours and it worked, are you sure that enemy has the runRequirement variable? Is T a Dragon?

Comment: Yes! I haven't run the code yet, since it won't compile because of the error, but T (for now) can be Dragon or Demon and enemy is its instance, of course... Did you try `T.runRequirement` and it doesn't get red? Or `enemy.runRequirement` as in the comment above?

Comment: Did you put the try{}catch(Exception e){} block? The other solution cannot work because compiler cannot know that T and enemy have the runRequirement static property

Comment: No, I didn't. But... I thought to code a public getter method to retrieve the private `runRequirement` field. Didn't work.